# Python-Mysql connectivity

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection

```
import mysql.connector as a

conn = a.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="darshan",database="PAYSLIP")


#CREATE a database or connect to one
conn = a.connect('Tablename.db')
```

getting error:-

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\any.py", line 3, in <module>
    a=mysql.connector.connect('Payslip.db')

  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 265, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 64, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Please help...

And please explain why it is not connecting in the answer...

Comment: Please format the question correctly! Its not understandable what part is your code and what are other things

Comment: The information you provided has a lot of inconsistency, the only thing that gives some clue is the TypeError message indicating 2 parameters are being passed instead of 1